# How to automatically run a stored procedure on scheduler basis?

Tags: sql-server

I want to execute a stored procedure automatically at every night. How can I do it. Please guide me with steps to achieve this target.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19):

You can create a job with the SQL Server Agent.

[image]

Right-click on the Jobs folder to open the menu, select New Job:

[image]

When you create a new job a window will open and you will provide the details of you job that you want to create. Including:

- Name - in the General tab
- Steps - can run a SQL script, SSIS package, stored procedure
- Schedule - recurring, weekly, daily, etc. at the frequency that you pick.

Here is a [Step by Step by Guide to creating a SQL Job](https://web.archive.org/web/20180805020140/http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/step_by_step_guide_to_add_a_sql_job_in_sql_server_2005.aspx)

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman Fixed the link with one to the internet archive

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyTask
 AS
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --  For executing the stored procedure at 11:00 P.M
    declare @delayTime nvarchar(50)
    set @delayTime = '23:00'

    while 1 = 1
    begin
        waitfor time @delayTime 
        begin
            --Name for the stored proceduce you want to call on regular bases
            execute [DatabaseName].[dbo].[StoredProcedureName];
        end
    end
END
```

Then,

```
-- Sets stored procedure for automatic execution.
sp_procoption    @ProcName = 'MyTask',
                @OptionName = 'startup',
                @OptionValue = 'on'
```

Reference:

[sp_procoption (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181720.aspx)

Sets or clears a stored procedure for automatic execution. A stored procedure that is set to automatic execution runs every time an instance of SQL Server is started.

[WaitFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx)

Blocks the execution of a batch, stored procedure, or transaction until a specified time or time interval is reached, or a specified statement modifies or returns at least one row.

Comment: Does having this stored proc running infinitely take up a lot of resources?  That is, will it slow down the general performance of the database?

Comment: `Is the specified period of time that must pass, up to a maximum of 24 hours` from MSDN. Is there anyway for this to be up to a year?

Comment: How to check if the procedure has been scheduled successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution is,

Create your stored procedure 
Write the SQL Job (below are the steps)

http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/step_by_step_guide_to_add_a_sql_job_in_sql_server_2005.aspx

In Step 5 configure stored procedure that you created.