# How to run job schedular in ms-sql in your remote desktop server if there is no sql server agent option

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I Want to run job schedular on network service but while connection to that server i dont see the option of sql server agent.How to run job schedular in ms-sql in your remote desktop server if there is no sql server agent option in remote server.I am using asp.net and ms-sql.

Comment: Can't you use the normal Windows Task Scheduler (under Administrative Tools)?

Comment: How give me some idea I am new in this field..

Comment: If there's no option for SQL Server Agent, then you probably have an edition of SQL Server (most like **Express**) that doesn't support SQL Server Agent. There's really no way to make the job scheduling magically appear if that is the case .....

Comment: say u dont no ok..

Comment: what is this job doing? Does it only executes queries or stored procedures?

Comment: if it does, have a look at sp_procoption, also supported in SQLExpress: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158158/how-to-automatically-run-a-stored-procedure-on-scheduler-basis

Comment: Actually I want to call a stored procedure in job when the data in a table exceeds than 30000 it will first create backup and then delete the particular table that i want to delete.So for that i need sql server agent which is shown to my local database but not shown on remote server